# Alt+Shift shortcut works unreliably in AHK

Tags: autohotkey

I'm running AHK on Windows 10 to be able to use CapsLock for language switching (it's not the only purpose, though).

Here's the relevant part of the script:

```
SetCapsLockState, AlwaysOff
+CapsLock::CapsLock

*CapsLock::Send, {ALTDOWN}{SHIFTDOWN}{SHIFTUP}{ALTUP}
```

The shortcut works kind of unreliably, like it wouldn't switch the language once every three or four times, or something like this.

What could be the problem here?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try it like so:

```
SetCapsLockState, off  ;  may work with SetCapsLockState, AlwaysOff
+CapsLock::  ;  Shift CapsLock toggles CapsLock state
    if GetKeyState("CapsLock", "T") = 1
        SetCapsLockState, off
    else if GetKeyState("CapsLock", "F") = 0
        SetCapsLockState, on
return

*CapsLock::Send, {ALTDOWN}{SHIFTDOWN}{SHIFTUP}{ALTUP}
```

EDIT:  Hmmm.  I had problems at first with `+CapsLock` not toggling.  Try this:

```
SetCapsLockState, off  ;  may work with SetCapsLockState, AlwaysOff
+CapsLock::  ;  Shift CapsLock toggles CapsLock state
    if GetKeyState("CapsLock", "T") = 1
        {
        MsgBox CapsLock going off
        SetCapsLockState, off
        }
    else if GetKeyState("CapsLock", "F") = 0
        {
        MsgBox CapsLock going on
        SetCapsLockState, on
        }
return

*CapsLock::
    MsgBox CapsLock pressed without shift
    Send, {ALTDOWN}{SHIFTDOWN}{SHIFTUP}{ALTUP}
return
```

And see if the capslock MsgBox is triggered by pressing shift+capslock

HTH, Let us know, YMMV

Comment: thanks for this. unfortunately, the result is the same: sometimes CapsLock just wouldn't switch language until I press it two or three times.

Answer (score -1):

This is from somewhere on the internet:

```cs
SetCapsLockState, off
+Capslock::CapsLock
*Capslock::LangSwitch(1)
*Capslock up::LangSwitch(1)

LangSwitch( iKeyDownUp=0 )
{
    static tickLast
    IfEqual,iKeyDownUp,1
    {   tickLast=%A_TickCount%
        return
    }
    IfEqual,iKeyDownUp,2
        If( A_TickCount-tickLast>200 )
            return

    HKL:=DllCall("GetKeyboardLayout", "uint",GetThreadOfWindow(), "uint")

    HKLnum:=DllCall("GetKeyboardLayoutList","uint",0,"uint",0)
    VarSetCapacity( HKLlist, HKLnum*4, 0 )
    DllCall("GetKeyboardLayoutList","uint",HKLnum,"uint",&HKLlist)
    loop,%HKLnum%
    {   if( NumGet( HKLlist, (A_Index-1)*4 ) = HKL )
        {   HKL:=NumGet( HKLlist, mod(A_Index,HKLnum)*4 )
            break
        }
    }
    ControlGetFocus,ctl,A
    SendMessage,0x50,0,HKL,%ctl%,A ;WM_INPUTLANGCHANGEREQUEST

    ;show traytip
    LOCALE_SENGLANGUAGE=0x1001
    LOCALE_SENGCOUNTRY=0x1002
    VarSetCapacity( sKbd, 260, 0 )
    VarSetCapacity( sCountry, 260, 0 )
    DllCall("GetLocaleInfo","uint",HKL>>16,"uint",LOCALE_SENGLANGUAGE, "str",sKbd, "uint",260)
    DllCall("GetLocaleInfo","uint",HKL & 0xFFFF,"uint",LOCALE_SENGCOUNTRY, "str",sCountry, "uint",260)
    traytip,%sKbd%,%sCountry%
    SetTimer,REMOVE_TOOLTIP,500 ;0.5 second
    return
REMOVE_TOOLTIP:
    SetTimer,REMOVE_TOOLTIP,off
    traytip
    return
}
```